# How would a closed conductor with only 1 layer of (atoms/molecules) behave if a charge is placed inside it?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law, conductors

I have quite a few questions actually related to this .

1. Is it possible to have such a situation practically?
2. If theoretically possible, how would the system behave?

Comment: Charged buckyballs? Classically the charge should be mostly localized on the outside of the molecule and distributed over the surface (with lot's of potentially excited quantum states!), but I can't find a paper that discusses the theoretical reason why an exception to the classical Faraday cage can't exist in the quantum world so I stop at waving my foam hand.

Comment: Ah! Take a look at this: http://www-als.lbl.gov/index.php/holding/281-photoexcitation-of-a-volume-plasmon-in-buckyballsfor-molecules-made-from-a-single-element-buckyballs-carbon-60-are-very-large-they-mark-the-transition-from-atoms-to-solids-in-atoms-and-small-molecules-the-behavior-of-electrons-is-accounted-individua.html